# How to change size of several selected tracks in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, altium, designer

Just that. I know how to change ALL tracks to the same size, but cannot find a way to select several ones and change the size of them.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select multiple track by holding Shift and clicking with the left mouse buttom over the desidered track. When the desired track are selected, from the "PCB inspector" windows you can change the track width.[image: Altium PCB inspector window]

Comment: Yep, the PCB Inspector is a very powerful tool. It's got all sorts of capabilities

Comment: Access the PCB Inspector panel by:

Clicking the PCB button at the bottom-right of Altium Designer when the PCB Editor is active then selecting the PCB Inspector entry from the pop-up menu.

( A friend didn't know how to access the PCB Inspector so added this comment ;) )